# Communicating between 2 panels

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

While reading tutorial for wxWiidgets I saw this [Tutorial](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/wxwidgetstutorial/firstprograms/) where author has created 2 subclasses of **wxPanel**, **LeftPanel** and **RightPanel**.

Left has 2 buttons, clicking which the text on right updates. Now there is another class **Communicate** which has one member **wxPanel** of which left and right panel are child.

Left Panel has a method ->

```
void LeftPanel::OnPlus(wxCommandEvent & WXUNUSED(event))
{
  count++;

  Communicate *comm = (Communicate *) m_parent->GetParent();
  comm->m_rp->m_text->SetLabel(wxString::Format(wxT("%d"), count));
}
```

where **m_text** is a public member of Right Panel.

I doubt if this is a good way of communicating.
My Question - Is this correct way of communicating? What will be a better method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also saw the tutorial you are talking about. I think this is a good way of communicating as it uses the connect event methods of wxwidgets (read the events for more details). I'm no expert in wxwidgets, but i've always wrote my apps using this way of associating events of a class widgets to a function of the class and then this functions locate the object that it has to change the properties.

Anyway if you consider that this event (of pushing the plus button) would happen really often and, specially, if you had too many functions/buttons like the plus and minus of the tutorial, one could define the m_text at the constructor:

in header:

```
wxStaticText *m_textlp;
```

in construtor:

```
m_textlp = ( (Communicate *) m_parent->GetParent() )->m_rp->m_text;
```

such that the function would be only:

```
void LeftPanel::OnPlus(wxCommandEvent & WXUNUSED(event))
{
  count++;
  m_textlp->SetLabel(wxString::Format(wxT("%d"), count));
}
```

Comment: This will only work if the the left panel is constructed before the right panel, otherwise the assignment of m_textlp will be dereferncing an uninitialized pointer.  But if you construct the left panel first, then it cannot use the same technique to communicate with the right.

Comment: @ravenspoint in this example, the left panel is constructed before the right panel, so didn't get why you said it can't use the same technique.

Comment: Because the right panel will not have been initialized when left panel attempts to initialize m_textrp.

Comment: @ravenspoint then you meant: "This will only work if the right panel is constructed before the left panel", right? That's true, but doing this doesn't make left panel unable to use this techinique to comuniquate with right (i just tested and it works fine)